# Wi-Fi connected but no internet access with Atheros in 16.04 on Acer Aspire E15

Tags: wireless, acer, atheros, aspire

I am dual-booting 16.04 with Windows 10 on an Acer Aspire E15 E5-575G-76YK. The Wi-Fi worked fine (but on the slow side) after installation, but more recently it will lose the internet connection despite still being connected to the network. It started happening once every hour or two, but now it can hardly keep the internet connection for a couple minutes before it drops. The only way to regain internet access is to restart network-manager several times, and then it only lasts for minute or two before cutting out again.

The output of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; dmesg | grep ath10k` is:

```
    03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device [11ad:08a6]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
--
04:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 12)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1025:1094]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
[    2.191992] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: pci irq msi-x interrupts 8 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    2.448292] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    4.321196] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: qca9377 hw1.1 (0x05020001, 0x003821ff sub 11ad:08a6) fw WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 fwapi 5 bdapi 2 htt-ver 3.1 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1 features ignore-otp
[    4.321199] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[    4.327183] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[    6.626532] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[   10.368161] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[   93.957264] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[   94.009502] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[  132.841153] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
```

There have been similar questions such as [1] and [2] below but they haven't been answered. And this isn't a duplicate question of [3] - I have the ath10k drivers installed. Plus, the wireless did work somewhat well at some point, and has degraded over the past week to where it is now.

For what it's worth, the wireless on this computer has never gotten faster than 5 Mb/s in either Windows or Ubuntu.

If it's helpful, output of `iwconfig` is:

```
wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"*********"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 00:1A:1E:8A:F6:21   
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=59/70  Signal level=-51 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:44   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp4s0f1  no wireless extensions.
```

[1] [Internet drops on Ubuntu 16.04 running on Acer E15](https://askubuntu.com/questions/839961/internet-drops-on-ubuntu-16-04-running-on-acer-e15)

[2] [Wi-Fi disconnects](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689579/wi-fi-disconnects)

[3] [No Wifi in Qualcom Atheros - Ubuntu 16.04 - Acer Aspire E 15](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763080/no-wifi-in-qualcom-atheros-ubuntu-16-04-acer-aspire-e-15)

Comment: Does the results for `iwconfig` differ when you have problems?

Comment: Nope, not at all.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. What did you do?

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question about a week ago. Idk but maybe this will help
[Rtl8723be WiFi incredibly weak](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883673/rtl8723be-wifi-incredibly-weak/883688#883688)

Comment: No dice. My network controller is a Qualcomm Atheros Device. Apparently the Ethernet controlder is a Realtek Semiconductor device (RTL8111/8168/8411) but adding the options to modprobe as suggested in the link you posted doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I am having this problem as well, similar setup (dual boot Ubuntu 16.04 + Windows 10), with the QCA6174, but on a Blade laptop.

The suggested setup according to Killer Networking [here](http://www.killernetworking.com/driver-downloads/knowledge-base?view=topic&id=2) is as follows:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.164_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware*.deb
sudo modprobe -r ath10k_pci && sudo modprobe ath10k_pci
```

I'm currently trying with this firmware to see if there is any improvement, no issues at the moment, but time will tell.